# C# - Single use multiline string parser, need to expand for multiple of the same - how?

Tags: c#, string, split

Have written a quick 'n' dirty C# app to take a file which contains a block of text, and split it, populating a CSV - this works fine for a single block.

Edit: Each block of text gets parsed into a single row on the CSV.

Text blocks are of a standard format, so there is no deviation.

Can't think how I could extend functionality on this so that it can take a dump of text blocks, with an empty new line in between each.

e.g.

```
    texttexttext
    texttexttext

    texttexttext
    texttexttext
```

etc.

I'm thinking of using an arraylist of string array?
What would be the delimiter of the double new line?

Thanks!

Code:

```
string[] input = new string[6]; // to take in details from the body of the email - will change to a bigger one once I've written basic functionality for a single block...
        string[] output = new string[10]; // to create the output - ditto above on this
        string currentLine; // current string line used for input reading
        string curManip; // current string line being manipulated
        int counter = 0; // standard int counter
        var filestream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"m:\EmailParser\file.txt",
                                                  System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                                                  System.IO.FileAccess.Read); // read in file - will change to command line arguments next
        var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filestream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 512); // the file to be read e.g. the text file

        // Populating the input into an array to be read and manipulated
        while ((currentLine = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            input[counter] = currentLine;
            counter++;
        }
```

.... parsing logic goes here, then....

```
 string path = @"m:\EmailParser\output.csv";

        // This text is always added, making the file longer over time
        // if it is not deleted. Append mode so we can keep track of all the data
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            foreach (string line in output)
            {
                sw.Write(line+","); // comma separated values
            }
            sw.WriteLine(); // new line for next entry
        }
```

Do forgive the terrible style, it's been a while since I've coded anything...

sample data:

```
From: noreply@123.com
```

Sent: 06 June 2016 08:31:13 (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
To: 11A3 - Shared Mailbox
Subject: Change of job completion time. 1234567890
Joe Bloggs will be delayed on job 1234567890. Property No 10. Postcode ab11 2cd. Expected finish time Mon Jun 06 2016 09:45:00

From: noreply@123.com
Sent: 06 June 2016 08:31:13 (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
To: 11A3 - Shared Mailbox
Subject: Change of job completion time. 1234567890
Joe Bloggs will be delayed on job 1234567890. Property No 10. Postcode ab11 2cd. Expected finish time Mon Jun 06 2016 09:45:00

From: noreply@123.com
Sent: 06 June 2016 08:31:13 (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
To: 11A3 - Shared Mailbox
Subject: Change of job completion time. 1234567890
Joe Bloggs will be delayed on job 1234567890. Property No 10. Postcode ab11 2cd. Expected finish time Mon Jun 06 2016 09:45:00

(I know it's repeated, but it's basically this.)

Comment: "Hope this was clear enough..." Not really! how about posting the code?

Comment: What is the difference between parse 1 line or multi line ? If you use StreamReader (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94223t4d.aspx) then you read the file line by line.

Comment: I realise just how badly formed my question is... Ok bear with me, I'll add code and clarify.

Comment: Ok, added code etc. Also, difference here is that each block is a separate block of text, and each block gets parsed into a single line on a CSV. Thanks

Comment: I've been parsing very complex text file for 40 years.  Need sample of data with multiple blocks to be able to help.

Comment: Hey - I've added some sample data - working on a way to populate the array. Edit - actually I think I might know what I'm doing wrong... bear with me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
// replace input and output filenames as you wish
var inputFilename = @"m:\EmailParser\file.txt";
var outputFilename = @"m:\EmailParser\output.csv";

// StreamReader and StreamWriter are used together, so that no intermediate structure is necessary
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputFilename, Encoding.UTF8, true, 512))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(outputFilename))
    {
        bool first = true;
        string currentLine;

        while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // empty lines, with no relevant data whatsoever
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentLine))
            {
                // if not the check for "first", multiple empty lines would produce empty CSV lines
                if (!first) sw.WriteLine();
                first = true;
            }
            //lines containing the useful information
            else
            {
                // if not the check for "first", the comma would be needlessly added at the end
                sw.Write((first ? "" : ",") + currentLine.Trim());
                first = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you! I've modified it a bit, and got it to work!